# How to get system time using windows azure powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, azure-storage, powershell-3.0

How to find system time using windows azure powershell?
I want time only and it should be in 24 hour format.
I have tried get-date and [system.datetime]::now
I want only time. I don't want date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
```

HH is for 24 hour, hh would be 12 hour.